# interesting estimates for the heat equation in R^n

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have no idea to how to do the exercise below...   .Someone can help me ?

thanks in advance!

Exercise:

For the initial value problem

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\partial_t u = \Delta u  \\
u(x,0) = f(x) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$x \in R^n$, $t>0$, prove that the solution $u(x,t) = e^{t \Delta} f(x)$ sattisfies the following inequalities:

i) $$ || D^{s}_{x} u(.,t)||_p \leq c_s t^{- (\frac{n}{2r}  + \frac{s}{2})} || f||_q (*)$$

for $s \geq 0$ and $1/p = 1/q - 1/r$

(Hint of the book for i) :  Use that $u(x,t) = K_t * f(x) = \displaystyle\frac{e^{-|.|^2/ 4t}}{(4 \pi t )^{n/2}} * f(x).$

Use that $|| D^{s}_{x} K_t||_\infty = c_s t^{-(n/2 + s/2)}$ for $s>0$ and combine it  with Young's inequality)

ii)

$$ (\int_{0}^{+ \infty} || D_{x}^{\rho} (.t)||^{\sigma}_{p} \ dt)^{1/\sigma} \leq c || f||_q (**)$$

with $\rho \in [0,2)$ and

$$ 0 < \frac{1}{\sigma} = \frac{n}{2}(\frac{1}{q} - \frac{1}{p}) + \frac{\rho}{2} \leq \frac{1}{q}$$

(hint of the book for ii) : Define $(\Omega f)(t) = ||  D_{x}^{\rho} e^{t \Delta} f||_p$ .

Then by $(*)$ $(\Omega f)(t) \leq c t^{-1/ \sigma} || f||_q, t \in (0, \infty)$, hence the sublinear operator $\Omega$ is bounded form $L^{q}(R^n)$ into $L^{\sigma *}((0, \infty))$, (i.e $L^{\sigma}$ weak). Use Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem to get (**).

Comment: What is $D^s_x$?

Comment: $D^{s}_{x} f(x) = [(2 \pi |\xi|)^{s}\hat{f}(\xi)]^{*}(x)$, where the $*$ denotes the inverse fourier transform